# UndefinedVariableError: name is not defined but for sample code it works

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

One dataframe looks like this (it stems from a bigger one that was sliced by `workplace`, therefore the square brackets):

```
company_grouper[0] =
group    workplace    dep    employee   answer    question
a        w1           t1     smith      True      q1
a        w1           t1     smith      False     q2
a        w1           t1     smith      True      q2
a        w1           t1     john       False     q1
a        w1           t2     joe        True      q2
b        w1           t1     don        True      q1
b        w1           t1     don        False     q2
b        w1           t2     sean       True      q3
c        w1           t2     sean       True      q5
c        w1           t3     liam       False     q5
c        w1           t1     al         True      q1
```

So `workplace` is always the same, `team` doesn't matter, an `employee` can be in multiple `groups` and can `answer` the same `question` multiple times. I wanted to make a statistic and compare groups two by two because not all of them deal with the same questions. So firstly:

```
import itertools
g_8 = company_grouper[0].groupby('group')['question'].apply(set)
rows = []
for a, b in itertools.combinations(g_8.index, 2):
    rows.append({'Group1': a,
                 'Group2': b,
                 'NumberQuestionsG1': len(g_8[a]),
                 'NumberQuestionsG2': len(g_8[b]),
                 'Q_G1_G2': len(list(set().union(g_8[a],g_8[b]))),
                 'AllQuestions': len(company_grouper[0].question.unique()),
                 'CommonQuestions': len(g_8[a] & g_8[b]),
                 'Ratio': len(g_8[a] & g_8[b]) / (len(company_grouper[0].question.unique())),
                 'Ratio_pair': len(g_8[a] & g_8[b]) / len(list(set().union(g_8[a],g_8[b])))})
output_g_8 = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

The columns are unimportant for this post, the only thing that matters is that I take groups two by two, without repetitions. The above code works.

**The problem is when I am trying to compute the averages for each group within each pair:**

```
d_groups = {'Group1':'group1','Group2':'group2'}
result_8_partial = (company_grouper[0].merge(company_grouper[0], on='question', suffixes=('1','2'))
        .query('group1 != group2')
        .groupby(['group1','group2','question'], as_index=False)
        .mean())

statistic_8 = result_8_partial.merge(output_g_8[['Group1','Group2']].rename(columns=d_groups))
statistic_8_averages = statistic_8.groupby(
    ['group1', 'group2'], as_index=False
).agg(Average1=('answer1', 'mean'), Average2=('answer2', 'mean'))
```

**I don't understand why everything that I wrote here (see sample data below) works, but it doesn't work if I use that piece of data with the notation `company_grouper[8]`. I get UndefinedVariableError: name 'group1' is not defined.**

Here's the data to play around with:

```
company_grouper = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
                   'workplace': ['w1', 'w1', 'w1', 'w1', 'w1', 'w1', 'w1', 'w1', 'w1', 'w1', 'w1'],
                   'team': ['t1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't2', 't1', 't1', 't2', 't2', 't3', 't1'],
                   'employee': ['smith', 'smith', 'smith', 'john', 'joe', 'don', 'don', 'sean','sean', 'liam','al'],
                   'answer': [True, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, True],
                   'question': ['q1','q2','q2','q1','q2','q1','q2','q3','q5','q5','q1']})
```

EDIT: **How I got to the `company_grouper[0]` dataframe**:

```
df_big=
    group    workplace    dep    employee   answer    question
    a        w1           t1     smith      True      q1
    a        w1           t1     smith      False     q2
    a        w1           t1     smith      True      q2
    a        w1           t1     john       False     q1
    a        w1           t2     joe        True      q2
    b        w1           t1     don        True      q1
    b        w1           t1     don        False     q2
    b        w1           t2     sean       True      q3
    c        w1           t2     sean       True      q5
    c        w1           t3     liam       False     q5
    c        w1           t1     al         True      q1
    z        w2           t9     mary       True      q7
    z        w2           t9     mary       False     q8
    y        w2           t9     dan        False     q7
    y        w2           t8     ben        True      q9
    w        w3           t14    greg       False     q15
```

And then:

```
company_grouper = [g for _, g in df_big.groupby(['workplace'])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not getting something, you are trying to access company_grouper by 8, but that's a data frame?

Can you post your original company_grouper, I'm expecting that it is a dictionary, or a list, an not a dataframe.

Be careful using the same name for different things.

Comment: I will post it, but the original is indeed a dataframe. The sample that I posted at the end of my post is just a manually written dataframe so I could play around with my code, which works. Thank you.

Comment: I changed it to index [0] for simplicity, but the idea is the same, the code fails for every slice that I take.

Comment: I replicated all the steps and it's running fine.
And indeed company_grouper it is a list, with DF's inside

Comment: I know you don't have the [reputation to comment yet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), but just in case you are unaware, once you are able to comment, questions for askers should be made as comments instead of answers. There's nothing wrong with what you did, just a friendly FYI for the future! :)

Comment: I accepted the answer because you were right, you helped me look at the right thing, namely at the naming :) i had a problem because my original dataframe column was called groupId and not group, and the block of code with suffixes doesn't work anymore if I don't wrote "groupId1" etc! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you! happy coding


@ShaneBishop Yes, thanks for that, I'm collecting reputation at the moment.